# Can't create index, LOCK on materialized view

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I created a materialized view in Oracle. I used logs to enable/use fast refresh. Main table contains ~12 billion entries, joining table ~8 million.
Materialized view contains 366 million entries.
After the creation of the table which took 4h, we can't create a index.

```
create index Idx_TABLE_USERID
on SCHEMANAME.TABLE(USERID);
```

We get the error:

```
ORA-00054: resource busy and acquire with NOWAIT specified or timeout expired
```

Why there is a lock on the table? Does he fill the logs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default `create index` is a blocking DDL statement. Which means it can't start if there are outstanding transactions against the base table.

You can verify this by running:

```
create table t (
  c1 int
);

insert into t values ( 1 );
```

And then in a second session doing:

```
create index i on t ( c1 );

ORA-00054: resource busy and acquire with NOWAIT specified or timeout expired
```

Luckily create index has an online option. Specify this and the statement will become non-blocking. So if the in the second session you run:

```
create index i on t ( c1 ) 
  online;
```

it'll sit there waiting for you to commit/rollback the insert from session one. But as this is now non-blocking, other sessions can still insert/update/delete rows in this table.

It's not clear whether you're trying to create the index on one of the base tables or the materialized view. But in either case you're getting the error because another transaction holds the lock you need to create the index.

Comment: I want to create the index on the materialized view. The build of the view is done already successfull. There is no action on the table and we still cant create the index. But I think it is building a index on the view after the building of the view, so it is blocking us. Could this be possible?

Comment: If you use the online option then the database will build the index once whatever's blocking it completes. You could check `dba_dml_locks` and `dba_ddl_locks` to see what's preventing the index creation. I'm not sure what it is you think is building an index - could you clarify?

Comment: I mean after building the view it is creating an index in the background. But this shouldn't be. I started building the indices with `ONLINE` in a tmux session. Let's see if it is successful tomorrow. I think it will take a long time.